# How can I migrate from one version of boost to another in TortoiseSVN?

Tags: boost, tortoisesvn

I need to migrate from boost v.1.47 to v.1.48, last time I did this migration with next steps:

- delete whole boost folder (old version) in TortoiseSVN
- commit
- add boost folder (new version)
- commit

This method is not convinient

- there are more 10000 files in boost folder
- we lost history of file changes

Is there any way to do it in two steps?

I would like to have something like this:

- select old and new versioned folders and click "migrate" (all not used any more files will be deleted, files which are changed will be marked properly, new files will be added)
- commit

Regards, Maksim

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with boost but I think the [Vendor Branches](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.vendorbr.html) chapter in the Subversion book may be of help. If you complement it with a file compare tool and a Subversion client that allows to convert *missing* files into *deleted*, you'll get all the features you ask for.